# Pandas date range to single dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a CSV file with data such as the following,

```
Week,rossmann
2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,8
2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17,10
2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24,9
2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31,11
2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07,9
2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14,8
2004-02-15 - 2004-02-21,10
```

I want to make a DataFrame with following data:

```
Day,rossmann
2004-01-04, 8
2004-01-05, 8
...
2004-01-11, 10
...
```

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the CSV as usual:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=r',')
```

and then use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings) to extract part of the `Week` based on regex patterns:

```
df['Day'] = df['Week'].str.extract(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})')
df = df[['Day', 'rossmann']]
print(df)
```

yields

```
          Day  rossmann
0  2004-01-04         8
1  2004-01-11        10
2  2004-01-18         9
3  2004-01-25        11
4  2004-02-01         9
5  2004-02-08         8
6  2004-02-15        10
```

---

Another way to do it is to parse the CSV with the regex separator `r',| - '`. This would split the CSV based on commas or the literal string composed of a space followed by a dash followed by a space:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=r',| - ', skiprows=1, header=None, 
                 names=['Day','rossmann'], usecols=[0,2])
```

yields the same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# to get the start of the week day
def week_starts(week_dates):
    w_start = str(week_dates)[:10]
    return w_start

# to get the end of the week day
def week_ends(week_dates):
    w_ends = str(week_dates)[12:]
    return w_ends

# import csv into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('d.csv',index_col=False,parse_dates=False)

# create 2 new columns for start of the week day and end of the day week
df['w_start'] = df['Week'].apply(week_starts)
df['w_end'] = df['Week'].apply(week_ends)

# create empty dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Days','Rossmann'])


# append day and rossmann into new dataframe
for i in range(len(df)):
    ross= df.iloc[i]['rossmann']
    j = pd.date_range(str(df.iloc[i]['w_start']),str(df.iloc[i]['w_end']),freq='D')
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'Days':j,'Rossmann':ross})
    df2= df2.append(temp,ignore_index=True)

print(df2)
```